# ui-grid scrollToFocus when sorting is applied to the grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've got a problem trying to set focus on the first row in a grid using the scrollToFocus method.

The issue seems to be centred around the sort direction:

```
 sort: {
    direction: uiGridConstants.DESC
 }
```

If I leave this out then it works as expected.  I can only assume that the row number is the row of the data before it's sorted and doesn't take into account any 'post' sorting.

Here's an example of the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/beWci0?p=preview

You'll see that when clicking to select the first row it actually goes to another row - the first in the dataset that the grid was bound to.

Any ideas on how to take in to account the row position based on the sorted results?

It's been put together from trimming down the example here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to select first row in the grid irrespective of sorting and filtering, you will have to look at the visible rows, ui-grid does not render all the rows in the data array. So the number of visible rows may be lesser than the actual data rows.

To select the first row you can do the following,

```
$scope.scrollToFocus = function( rowIndex, colIndex ) {
   var row = $scope.gridApi.grid.getVisibleRows()[rowIndex].entity;
  $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus( row, $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[colIndex]);
};
```

This will select the first visible row and set the focus on the third column. 
Plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/gWlY68?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, this works.  However, the documentation (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi) could be made clearer by stating that getVisibleRows returns ALL the rows contained in the grid.  Some people may infer that it returns only the rows they can see in within the visible boundary of the grid.

Comment: I have another problem with this but as you have answered my original question I've raised it as a separate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451462/ui-grid-keyboard-navigation-when-scrolltofocus-is-used)

Comment: @dubs the visible rows does NOT return all the rows.

Comment: can you provide any more detail on what it DOES do?  Here's a new plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/HFk8TJ which shows the total.